# How to disbale/enable logically wifi on Windows?

Tags: windows, wifi, netsh

To meet the constraints of my company, I must on a machine authorize only one active connection on a network. For this I need to control the activation or desactivation of wifi.

With **netsh** utility i can enable/disable **physically** the network card.

To display interface state :

```
netsh interface show interface "Wi-Fi"
```

To **enable** physically (with admin privilege) :

```
netsh interface set interface "Wi-Fi" admin=ENABLED
```

To **disable** physically (with admin privilege) :

```
netsh interface set interface "Wi-Fi" admin=DISABLED
```

On Windows we can enable/disable Wi-Fi **logically**. (Just click on network icone in task bar, then click on the wifi logo, the wifi interface is disabled.)

But with **netsh** it is not possible to enable/disable it **logically**. How can do it by CLI on Windows ?

Thank for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution by changing a registry key.
Using powershell in CLI prompt with admin privilege.

To display the wifi software status :

```
Get-NetAdapterAdvancedProperty -Name "Wi-Fi" -AllProperties -RegistryKeyword "SoftwareRadioOff"
```

To **enable** logically :

```
Set-NetAdapterAdvancedProperty -Name "Wi-Fi" -AllProperties -RegistryKeyword "SoftwareRadioOff" -RegistryValue "0"
```

To **disable** logically :

```
Set-NetAdapterAdvancedProperty -Name "Wi-Fi" -AllProperties -RegistryKeyword "SoftwareRadioOff" -RegistryValue "1"
```